# how can i pass branch name in webhook url?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, webhooks, github-webhook

Currently under the same gitlab, I configure webhook in `repo A` to trigger the pipeline of `repo B`, the url is similar to this: `api/v4/projects/project/ref/dev/trigger/pipeline? variables[WEBHOOK_BRANCH]= ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}` , but I can't get the branch name of `repo A` in the pipeline of `repo B`, is there any other way?